# How to render-print content type fields in an article?

Tags: theming, entities, nodes

I am building a Drupal website and came across with an issue.

I have created a content type called "comments" with 4 fields :

```
    -comment1 with machine name: **field_comment_1**

    - comment2 with machine name: **field_comment_2**

    - image1 with machine name: **field_image_1**

    - image2 with machine name: **field_image_2**
```

I have created an article and put the code below:

```
<div class="green-box-comment">
    <?php print render($content['field_comment_1']);?> 
    <?php print render($content['field_comment_2']);?></div>
<div class="green-box-images">
    <?php print render($content['field_image_1']);?> 
    <?php print render($content['field_image_2']);?></div>
```

Unfortunately nothing shows... Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The function that you are using is ok, but, where you are putting your code, in node.tpl.php?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am putting this code drirectly on the admin site of Drupal: add content -> then article. If I create it as a node.tpl.php how will I show it up on my page?

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is what I would do:

- Create a subtheme as per this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0i5P3QGm5s), let's call it mytheme
- Go to sites/all/themes/mytheme and create a file there called

  ```
  node--comments.tpl.php
  ```
- Go to modules/node/node.tpl.php, open it and copy eveything inside
- Paste that inside the node--comments.tpl.php that was created in second bullet
- Inside the `node--comments.tpl.php`, **substitute `print render($content);`** with your code

  ```
  <div class="green-box-comment">
    <?php print render($content['field_comment_1']);?> 
    <?php print render($content['field_comment_2']);?>
  </div>
  <div class="green-box-images">
    <?php print render($content['field_image_1']);?> 
    <?php print render($content['field_image_2']);?>
  </div>
  ```

  The reason we subsitute `print render($content);` with your code is that your content-type has 4 fields and through your code you render all 4 of them one by one, so nothing is left for `print render($content);` to do.
- Go to appearance, enable and set default mytheme
- Lastly, **clear cache** to be sure all the changes are picked up (configuration -> development -> performance)

In this way, I would achieve to have my styling changes in a subtheme. So anytime I want to change something I can do it there and it will override what would be shown by the base theme, without changing core. This is following Drupal's best practices and keep my styling seperate from core, which makes the site more robust and easily maintained (& upgraded)

note: by creating the file `node--comments.tpl.php` and following these directions, you will just change the output of the custom content type called: comments, while leaving the rest of the nodes to be handled by the node.tpl.php, without interference.

P.S. you can do without step 1 and go straight to themes/bartik/templates (if bartik is your default theme), create there the node--comments.tpl.php and continue from there, and although this is faster, I think it is bad practice for the reasons explained above :)

Comment: Many thanks for this very complete answer. Thanks to your explanation and example I got it working :)

Comment: you are welcome, glad I helped. In the future 1up the answers that you find helpful (when you obtain the reputation to do it, ofcourse!)

Comment: not only that: if the answer solved your problem exposed in the question you should mark it  as accepted ;) this is the way Stack exchange works I believe. And the way to thank the answerer efforts